# Confusing moment from Theorem 2.7 Rudin RCA

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

I am working with theorem 2.7 from Rudin's RCA book and one moment worries me.

[image]

[image]

Here Rudin uses theorem 2.5 which I added above.  Using theorem 2.5 we get that $p \notin W_p$. But how he concludes that $p\notin \overline{W_p}$?

I thought on this about a day but no results.
Also I found the similiar question in MSE but I can't understand its answer.

Would be very grateful for answer!

Comment: Since $p\notin K$, according to theorem 2.5 we can find an open set $W$ disjoint from $W_p$ such that $p\in W$. Now this means $p\notin W^c$, and $W^c$ is a closed set containing $W_p$, therefore $\overline{W_p}\subseteq W^c$ and thus $p\notin \overline{W_p}$.

Comment: @FrankLu, Brilliant answer! I made the analogous reasonings but I can't finish them! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

Theorem 2.5 guarantees the existence of *two* open sets $W_p$ and $U$, such that $p\in U$ and $K\subset W_p$. Also, critically, Thm 2.5 guarantees that $U\cap W_p = \emptyset$. If $p\in \overline{W_p}$ then every open set containing $p$ would have to intersect $W_p$. Thus, because $U$ is open and $U\ni p$ and $U\cap W_p = \emptyset$, we must have that $p\notin \overline{W_p}$.

Comment: Is your $W=W_p$?

Comment: @RFZ Yes, thank you

Comment: You claim that "If $p \in \overline{W_p}$ then every open set containing $p$ would have to intersect $W_p$?". Can you explain it more detailed?

Comment: If $p\in\overline{W_p}$, then there is a sequence $q_k\in W_p$ such that $q_k\to p$. Thus every open set containing $p$ also contains all but finitely many $q_k$, hence must have nonempty intersection with $W_p$. (This is an alternate characterization of the closure of a set.)

Comment: Sorry but Rudin suggests another definition of closure ( as @Frank Lu used in his above comment!)